How to embed a LibVLCSharp MediaPlayer inside an Avalonia window?
It seems that LibVLCSharp.Avalonia is rendering the video player on a separate window, which is causing issues for my application.
I am following the example code here, and it works well. However, I am having an issue where when I focus on one of the controls, the entire window loses focus.
Here's part of the code which displays the VideoView:
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto">
        <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Video Player</Label>

        <vlc:VideoView Grid.Row="1" MediaPlayer="{Binding MediaPlayer}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                       PointerEntered="VideoViewOnPointerEntered"
                       PointerExited="VideoViewOnPointerExited">
            <Panel Name="ControlsPanel">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#900000FF" Spacing="20">
                    <Button Command="{Binding Play}" Margin="20">Play</Button>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Stop}" Margin="20">Stop</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Panel>
        </vlc:VideoView>
</Grid>

I also exported my application to test it on my Linux (Hyprland) install, and when I drag the window this happens:

It's a bit hard to see since I had to unfocus the window to take the screenshot, but you can see that the controls are put into a completely separate window. This is obviously not ideal.
I was just curious if there is a way to embed the player inside the window instead of it being separate.

Don't start to Play() the video until the video view is made visible.
The video view can't know its window handle until the window is open, but libvlc expect the window handle to be known at the time you call the play function

Hi, thanks. I tried removing the vm.Play() call in VideoPlayer.axaml.cs, so now Play is only called when the button is pressed. I am still having the same issue (Maybe I misunderstood your original answer?)

I misread your question and thought libvlc was creating a separate window like it does in the case I described, you're just having issues with the airspace hack. See my other answer

@cube45 well, I am having the issue with a separate window. I moved play from OnLoaded to a button that you have to press, and the problem is still present. E.g. video plays in a separate popup window.

Thatns a separate issue. Libvlc does that if it can't find the window hwnd. Please start from the samples and enable verbose logs if ot still doesn't work

I misread your question : you're not asking about a separate window in the sense that there is another draggable window that is creates, totally unrelated to the first one.
Yes, there is what we call an "Airspace hack" in platforms like Avalonia and WPF : libvlc 3 can only render in a window handle it has (hwnd on windows, xid on linux...).
Avalonia and WPF renders the whole content in a kind of canvas, bit there is one window handle.
The key in Avalonia is to use a NativeControlHost, which in turn creates a native child window on top of the first one.
Since this is a new window, we cheat in order to be able to put content inside of the control, and we place it on a third window over the video window and we sync its position.
It's all very hacky and this is the kind of issue you might face. Not sure there is a proper fix for the window losing focus, since it is indeed a new window. The workaround would be to put your control next to your window and not on top of it, but you would obviously need to shrink your video view.
As for your question about if there is another way : there might be a very complex way in libvlc4 involving OpenGL/DirectX rendering, but last time I checked in WPF, we would have been limited by the WPF refresh rate, and I fear the same would apply in Avalonia as well.

Thank you for the detailed response. Actually I meant both - on windows it just unfocuses, but on Hyprland the window is completely separate when I drag it. I will look into OpenGL - but honestly my app is in the early enough stages to where I can change frameworks if necessary. Do you recommend anything more mature, preferably .NET-based, that would support an embedded video player? This is assuming there are no other alternatives to LibVLCSharp.Avalonia which I couldn’t find.

The fact that the video window doesn't follow the app's movement is a bug that should be filed to the libvlcsharp bug tracker.
As for a recommendation, if you only need to play a video, LibVLCSharp would likely be the easiest to integrate. Sure, there might be some missing pieces yet, especially in Avalaonia because the support is quite recent, but I don't know of any other lib that has a platform compatibility this wide. Contributions welcome :)
As for the OpenGL, that would be something that could be implemented in LibVLCSharp, so that you don't need to worry about it in your app

Thanks again. I've been waiting a couple days for my account to be approved on code.videolan.org, is there any way to accelerate this process?

I think you'd need to go to the videolan IRC and ask for it to be activated
